# listen for device changes using API state did change

Tags: swift

Im am using Mbient Lab API to talk to a device. Using the api I discovered there is a stateDidChange Variable that looks like this:

var stateDidChange: (() -> Void)? { get set }

How would I use this method in viewcontroller to detect a change in the device (such as another device has connected to it already) or can someone provide documentation on what this variable does. Link to the API is https://mbientlab.com/documents/metawear/ios/latest/Classes/ScannerModelItem.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply assign a block to `stateDidChange` and handle your logic inside that block.

```
let item = ScannerModelItem()
item.stateDidChange = {
   // Handle state change
}
```

Comment: thanks for the response! Now is there a way to know exactly what the change was? One of the things i'm having trouble doing is checking if the device has already connected to another iOS device

Comment: @AntonioRodriguez I'm not quite familiar with Mbient Lab since I don't use it myself, so I'm afraid you have to look to their doc for help.